# Compute digits of a number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

The question is what the last $10$ decimal digits of $2^{3^{4^{5^{6^{7^{8^9}}}}}}$ are?

I do not get the following solution and its motivation. I would appreciate if someone would shed light on it.

Observe the following congruences: 
$$\begin{align*}\begin{split}
 2^{n+4\times 5^9} \equiv 2^n &\mod 10^{10} &\text{ for } n\ge 10, \\
 3^{n+8\times 5^8} \equiv 3^n &\mod 4\times 5^9  &\text{ for }n\ge 0, \\
4^{n+2*5^7} \equiv 4^n &\mod 8\times 5^8 &\text{ for }n\ge 2, \\
5^n \equiv 5^7 &\mod 2\times 5^7 &\text{ for }n\geq7.
\end{split}\end{align*}$$
Now let $n=6^{7^{8^9}}\ge 7$. 
So then 
$$\begin{align*}\begin{split}
4^{5^n} &\equiv 390624 &\pmod{8 \cdot 5^8}  \\
3^{4^{5^n}} &\equiv 5765981 &\pmod{ 4 \cdot 5^9}  \\ 
2^{3^{4^{5^n}}} &\equiv 8170340352 &\pmod{ 10^{10}}.
\end{split}\end{align*}$$

Comment: I too look forward to an explanation of that solution. The power "tower" looks intimidating, but a much easier approach to the solution can begin with the observation that $2^{3^n} \equiv \{8, 12, 28, 52\} \pmod{100}$.

Comment: @Lisa: Would you mind writing out the derivation of your observation?

Comment: I had Mathematica compute `Table[Mod[2^(3^n), 100], {n, 20}]` and when I saw the results I was like "Oh yeah, of course." It made perfect sense to me last week, but I must admit that now I can't remember all of my reasoning.